# 'stringstream' argument order trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stringstream, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm experiencing a weird problem with `stringstream`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    float f;
};

wstringstream& operator <<( wstringstream& sstream , const Test& test )
{
    sstream << test.f;
    return sstream;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Test a;
    a.f = 1.2f;

    wstringstream ss;
    ss << L"text" << a << endl; // error C2679!
    ss << a << L"text" << endl; // it works well..

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is here:

```
ss << L"text" << a << endl; // error C2679!
ss << a << L"text" << endl; // it works well..
```

The only difference between these two statements is argument order. Why does the first statement fail whereas the second one works?

Comment: Some people that are not familiar with VS would surely appreciate the full error message together with the error code C2679 in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

The problem is that `ss << L"text"` gives you a `std::wostream`, not a `std::wstringstream`.

You only created an `operator<<` for `std::wstringstream`, so the next operation (which you're trying to do on `a`) fails.

## Long answer

When you write something like

```
ss << L"text" << a << endl;
```

you are not invoking a function with four arguments.

You are, in fact, chaining multiple operations:

```
((ss << L"text") << a) << endl;
```

This works because each `operator<<` operation returns a reference to the original stream object, so that you can continue chaining further operations on in this manner.

But because iostreams form an inheritance hierarchy, and because `operator<<` is applicable to *any* output stream, the return type from your operation on `wstringstream` is something a little less specific than `wstringstream`.

In fact, **`ss << L"text"` evaluates to a `wostream&`** (`wostream` being one of `wstringstream`'s base classes). The reference still refers to the same, original stream object... but it has a base class type.

So, your second operation involving `a` has the following active operands:

- a `wostream&` (on the LHS)
- a `Test` (on the RHS)

**But** you have no `wostream& operator<<(wostream&, Test const&)`. You only created a `wstringstream& operator<<(wstringstream& sstream, Test const& test)`, so there's no match.

So, in fact, when creating an `operator<<` for wide iostreams you should make it work for *all* `wostream`s (clearly there is no reason to limit it to `wstringstreams`):

```
wostream& operator<<(wostream& sstream, Test const& test)
{
    sstream << test.f;
    return sstream;
}
```

Going further, why limit yourself to wide streams? Why not normal ones too?

```
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& sstream, Test const& test)
{
    sstream << test.f;
    return sstream;
}
```

Now you will be able to stream objects of your `Test` class into `wostream`s, `ostream`s, and all their descendants, properly.

Answer (score 9):

Don't restrict your `operator<<` only to working with `wstringstream`, write it so it will work with any wide stream:

```
std::wostream& operator <<(std::wostream& sstream, Test const& test)
{
    return sstream << test.f;
}
```

or with any stream (wide or narrow):

```
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>&
operator <<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& sstream, Test const& test)
{
    return sstream << test.f;
}
```

Comment: Yes. The problem is that `ss << L"text"` gives you a `std::wostream`, not a `std::wstringstream`.

Comment: Absolutely this is the answer.

Comment: Yes but it does need filling out. It doesn't explain _why_ the problem occurs.

Comment: @Tomalak : While I agree that an explanation of the underlying problem here is warranted for a "complete" answer, I don't have time to type a thorough explanation at the moment. If a separate answer is provided explaining the "why" I'd be happy to vote it up.